# Order ArrayList of dates in decending or ascending order

Tags: java, date, arraylist

I have an array list of Dates and I want to order it by dates in ascending and descending order. Could anyone please provide a complete code snippet for this ? I have seen many questions like this but could not find a suitable answer.

List will be like this

```
         List<Date> dates= new ArrayList<Date>();
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated , Many thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since `Date` already implements Comparable, you can simply use:

```
Collections.sort(dates);
```

to sort in ascending order, and for descending order:

```
Collections.sort(dates, Collections.reverseOrder());
```